# Почему к странице не применяются стили?

Tags: gwt, javascript, css

Заметил странную особенность, если загружаю страницу со своего сервера (самописный C++ сервер), то к странице не применяются стили, если загружаю через встроенный, ant devmode, все нормально. В чем может быть проблема? Сишный сервер стили отдает.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте FireBug или Chrome DevTools и посмотрите, какие ресурсы сервер не хочет отдавать, как надо.